# Mysql - Use a LIKE operator in Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, subquery

Who can help me solve this issue?

I have table A with a column with id's.
A row can be empty or has one or more id's. If there are more id's in a row then they are comma seperated:

```
5f7c4738dcf5d
5f8571d05cffb,5f8574dc6a681,5f99d6d30b3ad
null
5f8ff7f6514ef,5f8fd1eac16a7
```

In table B I have also id's. But just one id per row.

Now I want to select all the rows in table B if the same id does not exist in table A.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM B 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ids FROM A WHERE A.ids LIKE '%B.id%')
```

If i use the = operator (instead of LIKE) then it works but the comma seperated values are not selected.

How can I compare the comma separated values?

Comment: Focus on the last line of GMB's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` and  `find_in_set()`:

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where find_in_set(a.ids, b.id))
```

That said, your primary effort should go into fixing your data model. Storing CSV lists in a relational dabatase is bad practice, and should be avoided; instead, each element of `a(ids)`should go on a separate row. Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Also thanks the recommendation, I was not aware of this! I will fix this with a link table.